# How to generate java classes using more than 2 graphqls schema file?

Tags: java, maven, graphql

I am trying with below maven plugin but getting error: Execution default of goal io.github.deweyjose:graphqlcodegen-maven-plugin:1.14:generate failed: Schema File: /Users/abc/Documents/GitHub/application-name/src/main/resources/graphql does not exist! ->

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.deweyjose</groupId>
                <artifactId>graphqlcodegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <SchemaPaths>
                                <SchemaPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/el/schema1.graphqls</SchemaPath>
                            </SchemaPaths>
                            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/el/graphql</outputDir>
                            <packageName>com.graphql.model</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <SchemaPaths>
                                <SchemaPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/pr/schema2.graphqls</SchemaPath>
                            </SchemaPaths>
                            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/pr/graphql</outputDir>
                            <packageName>com.graphql.model</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I am not getting any clue for the error why it is searching /resources/graphql folder.